# make select2 dropdown only drop down after at least one letter is typed

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have a form input with which I am using select2 to use tag/dropdown menu. It has an id of tag_list and use this jquery:

```
$('#tag_list').select2({
    placeholder: 'a short description of what this content explains',
    tags: true
});
```

Right now what happens is when the user clicks on the input box, which causes a cursor to appear at the beginning of the box, a dropdown menu appears with all of the created tags. The user can type and the dropdown will filter results based on what the user types, or the user can create a new tag.

I want to know: can I make it so that the dropdown menu appears only after at least one (or n) letters have been typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by passing minimumInputLength with number you want.

```
$('#tag_list').select2({
    placeholder: 'a short description of what this content explains',
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tags: true
});
```

checkout example here.

http://select2.github.io/select2/

Comment: thanks! do you know if there is a way to remove the 'please enter 2 or more..' ?

Comment: it's by default functionality of plugin. you can check it's class and hide it with css.

Comment: understood thanks. I'm still a newbie to front-end development :S

Comment: put .select2-no-results{display:none;} but it's con you will also not get no match found text in display.

Comment: but when there is no match found it adds it to the data base anyways